# nltk.twitter is giving 401 error

Tags: python, nltk, twitter-oauth, data-analysis

I am trying to collect tweets and extract the text part for my project. I tried many ways and most of them works just fine for me. Though I stumbled upon this nltk.twitter package and some code snippets to do the same work. The codes are pretty clean and i want to use that. But even the simplest code is giving me 401 error though I have my account at twitter developers' and have all the four keys required.

```
from nltk.twitter import Twitter
tw = Twitter()
tw.tweets(keywords='love, hate', limit=10)
```

I took this example from http://www.nltk.org/howto/twitter.html#simple and tried every example that is given. None of them works. And apparently I cannot find why. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things that may have caused this. But I bet it is the time issue as nltk is trying to use the streamer and the time of your computer/server is out of sync.

Also make sure you install nltk completely. Try

```
import nltk
dl = nltk.downloader.Downloader("http://nltk.github.com/nltk_data/")
dl.download()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nltk.twitter requires your credentials.txt file path in TWITTER environment variable and the data inside the text file has to be entered correctly.

For example:
`app_key=YOUR CONSUMER KEY

app_secret=YOUR CONSUMER SECRET

oauth_token=YOUR ACCESS TOKEN

oauth_token_secret=YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET
`

There should be no space before of after the '='. Also, don't put the key in quotes like "YOUR CONSUMER KEY".

This solved my issue with 401.